# sbt assembly artifacts copied to staging directory

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I am building a project inside of a docker container with the sbt-assembly plugin. The container has a `.sbt` directory in its home for repository overrides. When I build the project with `sbt assembly` from a given location `/project` the entire project is copied into `~/.sbt/0.13/staging/eac123asdf/project` and the build artifacts are located in the `target` directory within?

Comment: This isn't phrased as a question. I can't parse what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was the project was mounted in volume `/project` as user `core` (coreOs) which has a different UID than the user defined inside of the container. SBT when run inside of the container was not privileged to write to `/project/target/...` and would fall back to performing the build inside of `~/.sbt/0.13/staging/eac123asdf/project`. Still trying to track down where this is documented.

TLDR: Make sure the user defined inside of the container has write permissions to the project directory.